# My cursor turned into a "plus" shape and unable to click

Tags: ubuntu, click, cursor

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and my cursor turned into a thick plus, that looks like the following screenshot:

[image: cursor]

I can move my cursor, however the mouse buttons are frozen and I am unable to click anything.
Rebooting the system can fix it, but I need to  fix this without doing so. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by

```
killall -KILL import
```

from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031400/mouse-cursor-turned-into-a-thick-plus-cannot-click-but-mouse-can-move

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in your terminal:
Type
`bg`
press Enter.
Then press
`cntl+c`

Answer (score 0):

You may be stuck in a sub-shell. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> to get out and log in again.

I got into this state when I had Python script without a [`#!`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), that had a Python import statement. When I ran it, all mouse and keyboard input was expected from the sub-shell, so typing and clicking does nothing. I could not run **fg**, **bg** or **kill**, enter control characters or anything else.